# I want Show only One Database By clicking on a widget,

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem Is I have Created a Firebase Database and User can Upload data is into it `post screen` .
After That User data are Fetched on `IslamicHistoryScreen`. in this screen user data are Stored in a
Widget called `listview()` On this widget I added container and add user data such as `Heading and author name` . And i Wrapped this widget with Colum and inwell (For Ontap). i also added a container and wrapped up in Visblitiy widget so that User can View listView by taping in it.

here Is My problem On the `Post Screen` User can added  How many data as They Want And every data should be loaded at `IslamicHistoryScreen` But The Problem Is by Ontaping on a Listview() it Open all the data That are available on listview .
for Example
you have Created a Button and by Ontapiing on Button it should visble a container with data that are stored in your Firebase. And user 3 datas a,b,c on diffrent keys. and these data are show and three diffrent buttons are made automatically and stored those three data on each button.
if user click on 1st Button it should only show 'a' But Here it also other Buttons data

`please help me Fox this`

```
islamic screen
```

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../Provider/Auth_Provider.dart';

class IslamichIstoryScreeen extends StatefulWidget {
  const IslamichIstoryScreeen({super.key});

  @override
  State<IslamichIstoryScreeen> createState() => _IslamichIstoryScreeenState();
}

class _IslamichIstoryScreeenState extends State<IslamichIstoryScreeen> {
  Query dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('IslmaicHistory');
  bool isVisble = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          height: double.infinity,
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query: dbref,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                Animation<double> animation, int index) {
              Map IslmaicHistory = snapshot.value as Map;
              IslmaicHistory['key'] = snapshot.key;
    

              return listview(IslmaicHistory: IslmaicHistory);
            },
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget listview({required Map IslmaicHistory}) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print(IslmaicHistory['key']);
        setState(() {
          isVisble = !isVisble;
        });
      },
      child: Column(children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          height: 90,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 6,
              ),
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
                radius: 30,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/Islamic history.png',
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 4,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    IslmaicHistory['Heading'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.green[900],
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text('Written By',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.green[900],
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Text(IslmaicHistory['authorName'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.green[900],
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: isVisble,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            height: 300,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(
              IslmaicHistory['History'],
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green),
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

```
Post Screen
```

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:testsample/Homepage/IslamichIstory/Screens/IslamicHistory_Screen.dart';
import 'package:testsample/Homepage/IslamichIstory/islamicHistory_Bn.dart';

import '../../../Provider/Auth_Provider.dart';
import '../../../Widgets/custom_button.dart';

class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PostScreen> createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
  final HeadingController = TextEditingController();
  final HistoryController = TextEditingController();

  late DatabaseReference dbref;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('IslmaicHistory');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ap = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    int index;
    // for (index = 0; index < 10000; index++);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                  controller: HeadingController,
                  cursorColor: Colors.green,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green[900],
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    hintText: 'Heading',
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                  )),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: TextField(
                      controller: HistoryController,
                      maxLines: 1000,
                      cursorColor: Colors.green,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green[900],
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Write what you know about Islamic History',
                        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                      )),
                )),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: CustomButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Map<String, dynamic> IslmaicHistory = {
                      'Heading': HeadingController.text,
                      'History': HistoryController.text,
                      'authorName': ap.userModel.name,
                      // 'index': index
                    };
                    dbref.push().set(IslmaicHistory);
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => islamicHistoryBn(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  text: 'Post',
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```